# java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.LocalStrings bundle

Tags: java, sbt, javax.xml

I'm trying to run my app via `sbt run` but I get the following error when creating new Service (javax.xml.ws.Service):

```
Uncaught error from thread [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3]: null, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[default]
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:47)
        at javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:194)
        at javax.xml.soap.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:98)
        at javax.xml.soap.SAAJMetaFactory.getInstance(SAAJMetaFactory.java:74)
        at javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory.newInstance(MessageFactory.java:146)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<init>(SOAPVersion.java:175)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.api.SOAPVersion.<clinit>(SOAPVersion.java:84)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseBinding(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:578)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parseWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:460)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:234)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:194)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:163)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:348)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:306)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:215)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:196)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:192)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(ProviderImpl.java:104)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:77)
        at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Service.java:707)
        at yss.service.soap.SoapServiceUtils$.createServiceInterface(SoapServiceUtils.scala:72)
        at yss.service.download.api.account.impl.YSSAPIServiceImpl.traverseAccountRecursive$1(YSSAPIServiceImpl.scala:43)
        at yss.service.download.api.account.impl.YSSAPIServiceImpl.traverseAccounts(YSSAPIServiceImpl.scala:66)
        at yss.service.execute.ReportExecutor.execute(ReportExecutor.scala:76)
        at yss.batch.report.ReportBatch.execute(ReportBatch.scala:27)
        at common.batch.Batch$$anonfun$receive$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$1(Batch.scala:31)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
        at common.batch.Batch$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(Batch.scala:31)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:539)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:537)
        at yss.batch.report.ReportBatch.aroundReceive(ReportBatch.scala:14)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:610)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:579)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.LocalStrings bundle
        at java.util.logging.Logger.setupResourceInfo(Logger.java:1945)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:380)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager$SystemLoggerContext.demandLogger(LogManager.java:925)
        at java.util.logging.LogManager.demandSystemLogger(LogManager.java:581)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.demandLogger(Logger.java:452)
        at java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:553)
        at com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.soap.SAAJMetaFactoryImpl.<clinit>(SAAJMetaFactoryImpl.java:42)
        ... 45 more
```

I'm using:

oracle java version = "1.8.0_181"

sbt version = "1.2.7"

I have searched but I can't find the answer to fit my problem.
I'm wondering if there are conflict libraries or versions here?

Comment: Any luck? Don't mind posting posting the solution :)

Comment: got the same problem. any update?

Comment: I found that libraries conflict => import specific _saaj_ library  `"com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj" % "saaj-impl" % "1.4.0"`, and the problem was solved in my case